# Sharepoint2016 Custom List

Tags: sharepoint

Good Morning....

I am working on a project where I need to import several large excel Worksheets into a Sharepoint 2016 Custom List.  The custom list already exists, but I cannot find a way to import these lists.  There are approximately 11500 rows in the worksheets.

Is there a way to import these to existing lists?

Answer (score 0):

In general:

- If the columns are of the same type, and in the same order, you can display the list in the QuickEdit/DataSheet view and copy and paste from Excel to the list. You may want to create a new View to match the column layout in your Excel file.
- This needs to be done in small batches, and it will take a long time. (A recent test using SP Online and FireFox with 4000 items took 40 minutes to paste the the grid, and then after clicking to exit the QuickEdit view, almost an hour to complete the update to the list. Also, there is no visual indication that this update is occurring. I open a second browser to monitor the number of items in the list.)
- You may be better off writing a PowerShell script. Export the data to a CSV file and let PowerShell run in the background to process each row.